# activating a different <div> with a partial view in my Layout.html by getting the name of controller action or view

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'd like to get the name of my partial view in my layout page to determine which div is going to be active. Because of the design I cannot css this nicely so I went for a more sloppy approach.

In my _Layout.chtml The Renderbody loads my content. And here depending on which button I press, I get a map or a list. 
These are both functions in my controller and what I would like to do is get the functionname or partial view so I can then decide which  I want to show.

so I wanted to do something like this in my _Layout.chtml

```
 @if ( get the controllername or view == mapname or listname)
                        {                  
                        <div>
                              @Html.Partial("tabMap")            
                        </div>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        <div>
                              @Html.Partial("tabList")            
                        </div>    
                        }
```

Any quick fix to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

access the `RouteData` dictionary from the `ViewContext` Object

will be like this

```
@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"]
```

with the `RouteData` Dictionary you can get all the info needed about the controller , action and extra parameters names , depending on them output the data you want